# How To Increase A Value in Firebase With ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I want when i press a certain item to increase its value by x amount of time.

I have the value called "watchtime" and its as number, and heres the code when i click on the item that takes me to the item screen.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#f7f7f7" }}>
          {this.state.RecipeArr.map((item, i) => {
            return (
              <View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate("RecipeDetailScreen", {
                      Recipekey: item.key,
                    });
                  }}
                  style={styles.itemContainer}
                ></TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </View>
```

And this is when the component mounts on the item screen

```
 componentDidMount() {
    const dbRef = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("recipes")
      .doc(this.props.route.params.Recipekey);
    dbRef.get().then((res) => {
      if (res.exists) {
        const Recipe = res.data();
        this.setState({
          key: res.id,
          name: Recipe.name,
          category: Recipe.category,
          intro: Recipe.intro,
          watchtime: Recipe.watchtime,
          image: Recipe.image,
          ingredients: Recipe.ingredients,
          preparation: Recipe.preparation,
          isLoading: false,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Document does not exist!");
      }
    });
  }
```

My question is how to increase the "Watchtime" value when i click on a certain item.

Comment: Did you see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#increment_a_numeric_value?

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen i must have missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can call Increment for Firestore fields which triggers the backend to read the document and update the value. if the fiend doesn't exist, it will create it with a default value of `0` before incrementing your value.

```js
var videoRef= db.collection('video').doc('video_id');

videoRef.update({
    watchTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1234)
});
```

You can also decrement using negative numbers

```js
videoRef.update({
    watchTime: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-200)
});
```